# how to subset a list of dataframes by its rowlength in R

Tags: r, list

I have a list of dataframes and they all have the same column numbers.
The difference is some of them have only a couple rows whereas others have a few hundred rows.

Now before my next step, I would like to filter this list and subset only the dataframes in the list have longer than n rows.

```
d1 <- data.frame(y1 = c(1, 2, 3), y2 = c(4, 5, 6), y3 = c(5, 5, 6))
d2 <- data.frame(y1 = c(3),y2 = c(4), y3 = c(5))
d3 <- data.frame(y1 = c(1, 2, 3), y2 = c(4, 5, 6), y3 = c(5, 5, 6))

my.list <- list(d1, d2,d3)
```

dataframe 1-3 all have 3 columns but d2 only has 1 row. How do I filter this list so I get my.list with only dataframes longer than 1 rows, aka d1 and d3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below

```
my.list[sapply(my.list,nrow)>1]
```

Comment: Thank you! You got the first place, and others also proposed working codes, but I think it is fair to tick your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Using `purrr`.

```r
library(purrr)

keep(my.list, ~ nrow(.x) > 1)
```

Comment: Thank you, this one works and I reckon is the most elegant solution since it allows the chaining . Sorry I can only upvote, as ThomasisCoding got in early.

Comment: @ML33M I consider the answer you accepted to be the most fundamental one to R. So no issue with that being the accepted answer. Not everybody wants to live in the tidyverse and its pipelines! Remember, you should accept the best answer, not the first one. In this case, I think you did.

Comment: thank you for the kind words and reminder. I really like your answer too man

Answer (score 2):

A base R solution:

```
Filter(function(x) nrow(x) > 1, my.list)
```

Comment: Thank you, this one works too. Sorry I can only upvote, as ThomasisCoding got in early.